# Disconnect event fired after cilent reconnect - socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io for realtime communication. When inetrnet is not available for few seconds, then it will connect to server when the connection is establish and then it will immediately trigger event which will log in my clinet. After establishing connection, (i think) my socket.io on server side fire disconnect event after ~one minute (in callback function I log off my client), and that is my problem.

This is my server side. (a have `server.js` and he run `other.js` files, in object 'files' a have that files).

server.js :

```
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);//server listening on 8080 port

io.configure(function () {
    io.set('transports', ['websocket', 'xhr-polling']);
    io.set('log level', 1);
    io.disable('browser client');
});
var files = {
   control: null,
   terminal: null,
   messages: null
};

for (var game in games) {
    games[game] = require('./game_modules/' + game + '.js').listen(io, create_waiter(game));
}

  require('http').createServer(function (req, res) {

    var resultCode = 500;
    var resultText = '';

    var parts = require('url').parse(req.url, true);
    var matches = parts.pathname.match('^/([a-z_-]+)/([a-z_-]+)/$');

    if (matches) {

        var game = matches[1];
        var command = matches[2];

        resultText = games[game][command](parts.query);
        resultCode = 200;

        res.writeHead(resultCode, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end(resultText);

        }).listen(8081, "127.0.0.1");
```

control.js :

```
var control = module.exports = function() {
};

control.listen = function(io) {

    this.server = io.of('/control');
    this.onTerminate = onTerminate;

//********************************************************************************
    this.server.on('connection', function(socket) {
        socket.on('disconnect', function(data) {
          console.log(data); //after my client reconnect, disconnect event is triggered, and 
                             //console.log write 'close timeout'
```

After client reconnect, I do not want trigger disconnect event, or if disconnect event was triggered I want check in callback function: is my client connected and prevent "log off" for my client.

Thanks :)

Comment: Do you want to trigger a timeout event that waits for the client to reconnect, and then if the client does, do some `onReconnect` method, otherwise, if it times out, do some `onDisconnect` method?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: And, Do you know can I constant ping client and if client respond I will in variable (e.g. var STATUS) put value 1, or 0 if client not respond. Or if nor respond immediately call disconnect. I'm new in node.js and socket and relative new in javascript. Thanks! :)

Comment: You can, but I think it would be more effective if you called the ping whenever a new client connects or whenever another one disconnects. Then you can compare the previous ping of clients to the new ping of clients and use the difference to decide what to do.

Comment: When I sent heartbeat and If a client does not respond, I want disconnect them immediately. How to do that? I was reading that I must use 'heartbeat interval' or 'heartbeat timeout' or 'close timeout' but this not help.